# detached entity passed to persist but only sometimes?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

So I've read most of the other answers regarding this question and I guess I'm still confused about what's going on here.  I've got a class/table that has a many to many association with various tags.  Tags are in their own table and they're connected with a join table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item {

@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "item_tag", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
private Set<Tag> tags;

/**
 * @return the tags
 */
public Set<Tag> getTags() {
    return tags;
}

/**
 * @param tags the tags to set
 */
public void setTags(Set<Tag> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
}
```

Then in the service class I've got a method that first checks to see if a tag already exists and if it does I associate the preexisting one prior to saving a new Item:

```
public Item save(item item){
    if ((item!=null)&&(item.getTags()!=null)&&(item.getTags().size()>0)) {
        Set<Tag> newTags = new HashSet<Tag>();
        for (Tag tag : item.getTags()) {
            Tag t = tagRepository.findByValue(tag.getValue());
            if (t!=null) {
                newTags.add(t);
            }
            else newTags.add(tag);
        }
        item.setTags(newTags);
    }
    if(item == null){
        logger.error("Attempted to save a item , but item was null.");
        return null;
    }
    return repository.save(item);
}
```

Here's the odd thing to me, this code works fine for multiple POSTs with the same tags.  The preexisting tags are retrieved and associated with the new items.  But I have some code that populates data and when that code runs at startup I get the detached entity passed to persist error.  When I step through it's finding the preexisting tags, with their IDs and everything but then throwing that exception on save.  Any ideas?

Comment: change the call from repository.save to repository.saveOrUpdate()... might solve the issue

Comment: saveOrUpdate is not a method available in JpaRepository

Comment: my bad...that method is in hibernate...you can use EntityManager.merge https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge-T-  that is almost similar to that..